# Higher verbosity when using Record types in F# in comparison with Discriminated Unions

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, record, discriminated-union

```
let Method = { Name:string } //oversimplification

let method_parser =
  spaces >>. many1Satisfy isLetter .>> spaces
  |>> (fun name -> { Name=name })
```

Had I chosen to use a Method discriminated union, instead, and things would be a bit more succinct:

```
let method_parser =
  spaces >>. many1Satisfy isLetter .>> spaces
  |>> Method
```

I believe there is no way to avoid this kind of verbosity when using record types in F#. Am I right?

Comment: The single-element case is really a degenerate one, because as soon as there are more than one factor/summand, a record (product type) is not equivalent at all to a discriminated union (sum type) anymore. It's the other way around when you consume instead of construct: projecting from a record is easy, whereas case matching on a tagged union can be somewhat verbose.

Comment: (It looks like your edit really adds a separate question. Maybe ask it separately?)

Comment: It's funny you said that. I was at first writing it as a separate one, but then I figured out I should edit this one instead.. I'll follow your advice.

Answer (score 6):

A record is very similar to a discriminated union with just a single case. In some cases, I would also prefer a union, because it is easier to use. However, records have two main advantages:

- They give names to the fields, which partly causes the verbosity, but makes code more self-explanatory
  If you have small number of fields, you can use tuple or single-case union.
- They allow you to use the `{ info with Name = "Tomas" }` syntax for cloning records
  If you don't need this, you can use standard F# classes (which have more .NET feel)

If you want to get the benefits of records, but still use simple syntax for creating then, then you can define a static member for constructing your record:

```
type Info = 
  { Name : string 
    Count : int }
  static member Create(name:string, count:int) = 
    { Name = name; Count = count }
```

Then you can write:

```
// Simple example using the above type:
let res = ("hello", 5) |> Info.Create

// I expect this would work for your type like this:
let method_parser = 
   spaces >>. many1Satisfy isLetter .>> spaces 
   |>> Method.Create
```